# Concatenating pandas dataframes into one geopandas dataframe throws "the truth value..." error when trying to bring it into a geoseries

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I am trying to buffer a GeoSeries in geopandas; I have concatenated 3 dataframes together in pandas and converted them into a geoDataFrame using gpd.GeoSeries(cgdf).buffer(x) throws an error "Concatenating pandas dataframes into one geopandas dataframe throws "the truth value..." error when trying to bring it into a geoseries". I still get the error when I remove the variables and enter hard values.

```
cgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame((pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])[['id', 'date_num', 'longitude', 'latitude']])), geometry=geopandas.array.points_from_xy((pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]))).longitude, (pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]))).latitude), crs=4326)
cgdf.to_crs('esri:102001')
cgs = gpd.GeoSeries(cgdf)
workarea = cgdf.buffer(0.2)
print(cgs)
cgdf.to_file(str(id)+'_points.shp')
```

Data

```
id        date_num  ...   latitude                    geometry
139469   2.46302e+08  1.546907e+09  ...  38.772277  POINT (-74.53319 38.77228)
139554   2.46302e+08  1.546907e+09  ...  38.772277  POINT (-74.53319 38.77228)
256795   2.46302e+08  1.546908e+09  ...  38.781752  POINT (-74.47964 38.78175)
565534   2.46302e+08  1.546904e+09  ...  38.764730  POINT (-74.68761 38.76473)
...
[22 rows x 5 columns]
```

Everything was working until I got to buffering...
Original Code

```
cgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame((pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])[['id', 'date_num', 'longitude', 'latitude']])), geometry=geopandas.array.points_from_xy((pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]))).longitude, (pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]))).latitude), crs=4326)
cgdf.to_crs('esri:102001')
print(gpd.GeoSeries(cgdf[cgdf['date_num'].isin([0,9999999999])]).buffer(mdist(cgdf[cgdf['date_num'].isin([0,9999999999])])))
(gpd.GeoSeries(cgdf[cgdf['date_num'].isin([0,9999999999])]).buffer(mdist(cgdf[cgdf['date_num'].isin([0,9999999999])]))).to_file(str(id)+'_points.shp')
```

the mdist() in the buffer parameters is simply a definition to calculate the distance between the 2 input points; it returns a valid distance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm converting the a GeoDataFrame to a GeoSeries of which exists within the GeoDataFrame. So I should be using buffer = cgdf[cgdf['date_num'].isin([0, 9999999999])].geometry.buffer(x), x being the distance, as opposed to trying to convert the GeoDataFrame into a GeoSeries. I'm going to say the literature around geopandas didn't explain that well to me.